# Creating forms for models with references

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that references another, like so:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :content
end
```

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(Message.new) do |f|%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :category, :value => Category.first.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

Submitting this gives me:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in MessagesController#create
Category(#70229327985340) expected, got String(#70229321568640)
```

How do I do this right, so that the model is created with the correct reference?

I've gotten it to work by changing the form field to `category_id`, and adding `category_id` to `attr_accessible` in the model.  Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model has associations defined

```
  <%= form_for([@category, @message]) do |f| %>
      ...
      ...
   <% end %>
```

Where @category = Category.find(params[:id]) and @message = Message.new. (these should be in your controller). This will assign the foreign key and there will be no need for the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, the form field should be `category_id`, seeing as that's what you are storing. You aren't storing a reference to the category, which is what you should be doing.

It should really just be `Category.first`, to store the category, and leave the form as-is. I think this would work, it's been a week or so since I last played with rails, and my knowledge isn't huge.

Also, IDs shouldn't be `attr_accessible`, because they are automatically assigned, and should't be changed.

Comment: If `category_id` isn't declared as accessible, the controller complains that it "can't mass-assign protected variables" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you're on the right track here. The form field name should be `category_id` and `attr_accessible :category_id` will allow you to set this value through 'mass assignment'. Which is the technique used when you do `Message.create(params[:message])`. Without `attr_accessible`, category_id will be set to nil.